# Unable to connect to the API deployed in docker-desktop kubernetes?. Loadbalancer service not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, docker-desktop

I am trying to deploy and verify my API solution to docker-desktop kubernetes. I successfully deployed my application to docker-desktop k8s, I am able to run the application using swagger with the `kubectl port-forward` command. When I tried to apply deployment, service and loadbalancer yml files, I am unable to run the application in my browser. I am getting a message that localhost didn't sent any data. Below are my yml, docker files and screenshot of the error message in browser.

**Working option**
[image]

[image]

**Not working option**

Docker file
[image]

Deployment.yml
[image]

Service.yml

[image]

Loadbalancer.yml
[image]

**Browser Error**

[image]

**K8s Details**
[image]

Please check the above configuration on not working option and help me to identify where I did mistake.

Comment: Hi @Purushothaman, could you please add the output of `kubectl describe service/loadbalancer-service-demoeicoreapi` command to your question? You can add it by editing original question. Also, please add it as code formated text, not as an image, as you were doing previously.

Answer (score 0):

In your service YAML you have did mistake in ports

in your deployment container port is : **45678**

while inside the service target port is : **34567**

ideally, it should be **45678** or **80** as the service will be forwarding the traffic to a container or we can say the pods.

also same apply for the service **load balancer**

where the target port is not getting a match for the pod and load balancer port. due to this matches your traffic is not getting forward to the PODS and you are not able to access the service on the browser.

keep the load balancer port **45678** and target port **45678**

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I tried but no luck :(